# Spring Security, remote user becomes null after session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

Here is my Spring Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String sLogoutUrl_;

    private String sLoginPage_;
    
    private String sLoginSuccessUrl_;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        sLogoutUrl_ = LnProperty.getSecurity(LnProperty.LOGOUTURL);
        sLoginPage_ = LnProperty.getSecurity(LnProperty.LOGINPAGE);
        sLoginSuccessUrl_ = LnProperty.getSecurity(LnProperty.LOGINSUCCESSURL);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> {
            TomcatUser tomcatUser = LnProperty.getUser(username);
            if (tomcatUser == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
            }
            return new User(username, passwordEncoder().encode(tomcatUser.getPassword()), tomcatUser.getRoles());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(sLoginPage_)
            .loginProcessingUrl(sLoginPage_)
            .defaultSuccessUrl(sLoginSuccessUrl_, true)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler(sLoginPage_))
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl(sLogoutUrl_)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler(sLoginPage_))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler(String failureUrl) { 
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureUrl); 
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler(String successUrl) { 
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(successUrl); 
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }
}
```

I tried adding this to `htpp` but didn't work.

```
.and()
.rememberMe()
.alwaysRemember(true);
```

Is there a way to stay logged in even after session timeout? It's fine if session attributes are cleared but I want the remote user not to be nulled after session timeout. Only logout the user if the logout url is entered, the browser is closed, or cookies/caches are deleted.

Comment: No. As the user is stored in the session, no session, no user.

Comment: @M.Deinum but why it's different in tomcat hosted server? even after session timeout, the remote user is still in there. I'm just trying to copy what it does using vscode spring maven

Comment: I doubt it is still there or the session hasn't been cleaned up yet. Nonetheless you shouldn't rely on the user being there after the session timeout, unless you stop using the session to store the user information.

Comment: I'm currently migrating an old system that uses struts 1.0 to java 11 spring boot and I just discovered that the remote user logged in using tomcat built-in authentication never gets nulled after session timeout different to spring security. Thanks, I guess I will just set the session timeout to -1 for Spring

Comment: Tomcat build-in authentication might not use the session, if that uses basic-auth then each request carries the username/password and you automatically re-authenticate. Setting the session timeout to never is a bad idea, as each session will eat some memory if they live forever you eventually will run out of memory.